# Epub OPF (<item> sibilings with same ID attribute value)

Tags: xml, epub

For the `<manifest>...<item>` tags, can the item elements share the same ID attribute value if the case is different?

i.e.

```
<manifest>
<item id="Title" href="text/title.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="title" href="images/title.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: No.

XML Attribute IDs are not CaSe SeNsItIvE